# Indexes for google app engine data models

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql, bigtable

We have many years of weather data that we need to build a reporting app on.  Weather data has many fields of different types e.g. city, state, country, zipcode, latitude, longitude, temperature (hi/lo), temperature (avg), preciptation, wind speed, date etc. etc.

Our reports require that we choose combinations of these fields then sort, search and filter on them e.g.

```
WeatherData.all().filter('avg_temp =',20).filter('city','palo alto').filter('hi_temp',30).order('date').fetch(100)
```

or

```
WeatherData.all().filter('lo_temp =',20).filter('city','palo alto').filter('hi_temp',30).order('date').fetch(100)
```

May be easy to see that these queries require different indexes.  May also be obvious that the 200 index limit can be crossed very very easily with any such data model where a combination of fields will be used to filter, sort and search entities.  Finally, the number of entities in such a data model can obviously run into millions considering that there are many cities and we could do hourly data instead of daily.

Can anyone recommend a way to model this data which allows for all the queries to still be run, at the same time staying well under the 200 index limit?  The write-cost in this model is not as big a deal but we need super fast reads.

Comment: Do you need to be able to do inequality filters on those numeric properties or just equality filters?

Comment: For now, just equality filters.  Inequality filters may come in later but not for now.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to rely on the built-in support for merge join queries, which can satisfy these queries without an index per combination. All you need to do is define one index per field you want to filter on and sort order (if that's always date, then you're down to one index per field). See [this part of the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes) for details.

Comment: It is good to hear that the built in indexes can handle this. @Nick did this work before SDK 1.5.2?

Comment: Nick, thanks for your answer.  But even for this simplistic problem you can see that any real reporting app would want to be able to sort on different fields e.g. what cities had the hottest temperature on date x/y/z or when was the hottest day in palo alto. Without sorting ability how would you answer those queries from this simple dataset?

Comment: If i start defining one index per sort order per field, i am still going to hit the 200 limit pretty soon.

Comment: And not to mention, normally one needs sorting in both directions so thats 2 indexes per sort order per field, the 200 limit is even closer.

Comment: @Bryce This worked without sorting previously, but 1.5.2 introduced the ability to use composite indexes to do sorted merge joins.

Comment: @Yasser You could sort in memory, or you can have one index per field and sort order - those are your only options. They're both a lot better than the combinatorial explosion of indexes required previously! Bear in mind that RDBMSes don't provide a magic solution to this: without the appropriate indexes, they will simply perform queries the hard way, resulting in an unscalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it seems counter-intuitive but you can use a full-text search system that supports categories (properties/whatever) to do something like this as long as you are primarily using equality filters. There are ways to get inequality filters to work but they are often limited. The faceting features can be useful too.

- [The upcoming Google Search API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B7FyU9wW8Y)
- [IndexTank is the service I currently use](https://indextank.com/get-started/)

**EDIT:**

Yup, this is totally a hackish solution. The documents I am using it for are already in my search index and I am almost always also filtering on search terms.

Comment: I want to avoid a hacky solution.  I want something that can scale.  In the RDBMS world this is a simple problem to solve and i am trying to see how NoSQL ppl handle this issue.

Comment: @Yasser Actually, making these sorts of OLAP queries scale in the RDBMS world isn't simple. Executing them is easy, but executing them _scalably_ isn't.

Comment: @Nick i agree with you but until your dataset gets very large, in an RDBMS you at least have the ability to build any indices you want, simply at the cost of space, even if you keep your data denormalized.  Are you saying that google app engine is good only for apps that wouldnt scale well with traditional RDBMS?

Comment: @Yasser "...until your dataset gets very large..." <- That's called scaling. If you don't expect your data to get "very large", then the effort of learning how to work with big data in a NoSQL environment may well mean it's beyond the scope of your current project.

Comment: @Steve.  I see what you guys are saying but i think my issue is very specific.  If i have ten years of weather data (say a million records and no more), i can easily create an RDBMS app to sort and search on all those fields and filter whatever i like.  All i am asking is, can GAE let me do the same thing.  The answer i am looking for is either no or if yes, then how.  Scaling is obviously the next step but i dont want to learn the next step unless i know the solution to the first step!

Comment: @Yasser Your issue is not really specific as far as I can see. Plenty of us have approached similar problems when coming from the relational db world, which meant we had to learn new ways to store and retrieve data. If you can't stop yourself from running into the index limit (I'm no index expert) then you'll probably have to come at it from another angle, like computing query results upon data entry/update. You'll likely have a lot more data, but reads would be simple and cheap.

Comment: @Steve, how to store a million rows of weather data in a gae datastore such that data fields (all 12 of them) are sortable and filterable? Can you help me frame this problem in a simpler or more specific way?  If someone has solved a similar problem, id love to hear how exactly did they do it in addition to just general ideas about how to solve it.

Comment: Did you even read my comment? I've suggested an alternate solution to your problem which seems to fit your needs perfectly (low read latency but higher write latency/effort), and you've just asked me the initial question again. The thing is that these techniques really take some time to be comfortable with if you're used to a relational db. They're not something that is trivially implemented, or properly conveyed in a comment thread.

Comment: @Yasser The App Engine datastore is built for apps that scale, so we don't provide facilities for things that are inherently unscalable. Your options are 1) Define an index per sort order and filter field, 2) Sort in memory, 3) Generate composite indexes on write, as Steve suggests, or 4) Wait for SQL database support, which is coming soon.

Comment: @Nick 1 wont work because the 200 index limit will be crossed for just 10 sortable fields. 2 wont work because sorting a million records in memory may not finish in the allotted 30 sec request limit.  Precomputing every possible query result on every insertion for a million records within the 30 sec time limit seems even more impractical than 2.  I guess my only option is 4 for now.

Comment: @Yasser I'm not sure how you calculate 200 indexes for 10 fields. In any case, as I've already said, the datastore is designed for scalable apps, so it doesn't make it easy to do inherently unscalable things. On the same note, nonrelational databases really aren't designed for OLAP queries, which is what you're trying to do, in effect.

Comment: @Yasser There are plenty of ways to perform bulk work like that. A hint would be that tasks and cron jobs have 10 minute deadlines.

Comment: @Nick if you need all 10 fields to be sortable then you pair each of them with another field that determines the sort order, for a single column index like you earlier suggested.  So each of the 10 fields needs to be paired with 9 other fields i.e. 90 indices.  Add descending order and that's 180 indices. So my math is taking me very close to 200 if not 200 exactly - let me know if it is wrong.  My fields are definitely more than 10 though.  You have made it adequately clear that gae datastore is not meant to solve an OLAP problem like this so thank you for that.